# Android OpenGL ES fragment shader messing output color

Tags: android, opengl-es, colors, glsl

I'm using GPUImage for Android (CyberAgent) library for image processing. Specific, I have problem with GPUImageLookupFilter. Everything works great until I add variable for filter strength control. Then starts very weird problem with output colors on Galaxy Nexus.

Everything works great on emulator (Genymotion) and on real Nexus 5 (4.4.4) device. I can control how much color lookup table gets applied and everything looks ok, but on Galaxy Nexus output colors looks extremely yellow. With unchanged default fragment shader everything works great also on Galaxy Nexus.

**This is modiefied fragment shader:**

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2; // TODO: This is not used

uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2; // lookup texture

uniform lowp float strength;
void main()
{
  lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

  mediump float blueColor = textureColor.b * 63.0;

  mediump vec2 quad1;
  quad1.y = floor(floor(blueColor) / 8.0);
  quad1.x = floor(blueColor) - (quad1.y * 8.0);

  mediump vec2 quad2;
  quad2.y = floor(ceil(blueColor) / 8.0);
  quad2.x = ceil(blueColor) - (quad2.y * 8.0);

  highp vec2 texPos1;
  texPos1.x = (quad1.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);
  texPos1.y = (quad1.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g);

  highp vec2 texPos2;
  texPos2.x = (quad2.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);
  texPos2.y = (quad2.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g);

  lowp vec4 newColor1 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos1);
  lowp vec4 newColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos2);

  lowp vec4 newColor = mix(newColor1, newColor2, fract(blueColor));
  lowp vec4 newTextureColor = vec4(newColor.rgb, textureColor.w);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(textureColor.rgb, newTextureColor.rgb, strength), textureColor.a);
}
```

I have replaced:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(newColor.rgb, textureColor.w);
```

with:

```
lowp vec4 newTextureColor = vec4(newColor.rgb, textureColor.w);
gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(textureColor.rgb, newTextureColor.rgb, strength), textureColor.a);
```

I have tried many things to narrow down what cause the problem, but now I'm completely stuck. On Galaxy Nexus I even can't get right blue value from *newColor*. For testing purpose I simply tried to output only one channel to see whats going on and as output I got completely yellow screen when used blue value. Not like when using red or green values where I got image with one color overlay.

I have made several other tests and what I found was that if I use blue color value form *newColor1* or *newColor2* then in the end I got yellow tone on output. I have tested many variations and have tried also output colors like this

```
lowp vec4 newColor = vec4(mix(newColor1.rgb, newColor2.rgb, fract(blueColor)), textureColor.a);
gl_FragColor = newColor;
```

and output is ok, but if I change *fract(blueColor)* to, for example, 0.9 then again I got yellow overlay. Looks like that any color manipulation causes yellow tone on Galaxy Nexus and I can't understand why especially if on Nexus 5 everything is ok.

**Galaxy Nexus without strength control:**
[Normal output](http://i222.photobucket.com/albums/dd80/Obyyy/screen_1_zps76733d39.jpg)

**Galaxy Nexus with strength control:**
[Messed up colors](http://i222.photobucket.com/albums/dd80/Obyyy/screen_2_zpsb9e1743f.jpg)

Comment: Try it on an AVD and another device with a different GPU and OpenGL ES drivers.  Samsung has had a lot of problems with their drivers.

Comment: I have tried many variations and everything works as expected except on Galaxy Nexus so now I agree that it looks like it's some weird problem with Galaxy Nexus. To bad that I haven't access to another Galaxy Nexus phone, because now I'm curious if this is just my device bug or on all Galaxy Nexus phones this fragment shader outputs wrong colors. What's really weird is that if I simply make new vec4 variable to which I add modified values from newColor1 or newColor2, but don't use it, then anyway output colors are messed up.

Answer (score 0):

When using fragment shaders in Android a several unexpected behaviors might occur.

Every GPU has its own GLSL compiler and interpolator, which means that it takes your code and tries to optimizes it. If your's fragment code doesn't stands in the [standard](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf)(see Appendix A) of most of the GPU interpolator - a weird behaviors might happen. GPUs on which I experience weird behaviors are based on Adreno model( according to [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_nexus_i9250-4219.php) your GPU is PowerVR so lets set it aside).

Lot's of time the mess comes due to wrong pixels values. pixel is usually a vector of 4 floats. red green blue and alpha. the value of each one of them should be go from 0f to 1f.

So, try to clamp the vec2 coordinates that you're applying on your inputImageTexture2:

```
  highp vec2 texPos1;
  texPos1.x = clamp(0f,1f,(quad1.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) *
  textureColor.r));
  texPos1.y = clamp(0f,1f,(quad1.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g));

  highp vec2 texPos2;
  texPos2.x = clamp(0f,1f,(quad2.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r));
  texPos2.y = clamp(0f,1f,(quad2.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g));


  lowp vec4 newColor1 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos1);
  lowp vec4 newColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos2);
```

Note: I didn't try that solution since its might take some time to create the working env for that thread, but that solution did it for me a couple of times. Secondly, if it doesn't work - try to clamp other values in your shader.

Most important - test it on much more devices in order to get the big picture and decide whether or not it worth your time to fix it.

Comment: Same result. I have tried clamping other values too. I have tried every possible thing that I can think of. For some weird reason accessing newColor1 or newColor2 values mess up blue channel value and therefore in the end I got yellowish overlay. Looks like it's really isn't worth to spend time on this problem, because for now this problem is only on Galaxy Nexus device.

Comment: @Agris you're right. last option might be to disable this shader through config file to that device.